# profiling applications of functions using memory profiler in python

Tags: python, function, memory-profiling

I wish to profile my applied functions in my script. I have know how to profile the original functions when fully written out as such:

```
@profile
def get_df_from_sql(query_sql, df):
try:
    with open(query_sql, "r") as file:
        query = file.read()
        return pd.read_sql(query, conn)
        print('data succesfully extracted')
```

but when I want to do the same when applying this function I am lost. I have attempted the following

```
@profile (get_df_from_sql("query.sql,df1"))
```

but receive an an invalid syntax error, the line seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

this is **@profile** is a decorator, which is applied correct on the first line. To see the result of the function you should just do **get_df_from_sql("query.sql,df1")**.

Comment: I would like to view the profile specifically after inserting df1 in the function